# I´m trying to display images in a laravel view with if/elseif statement but it only shows the first image

Tags: laravel

I have this table:

```
<tbody>
                @foreach($datosClase as $datoClase)
                  @php
                      $movimiento=($datoClase->total_calmado_movimiento/$datoClase->total_intervalos_movimiento)*100;
                      $ritmo=($datoClase->total_calmado_ritmo/$datoClase->total_intervalos_ritmo)*100;
                  @endphp

                <tr>
                    <th>{{$asignaturas[$loop->index]['name']}}</th>
                    <th>{{$periodos[$loop->index]['time']}}</th>
                    <th>{{$periodos[$loop->index]['timeFinish']}}</th>
                    <th>{{$movimiento}}</th>
                    <th>{{$ritmo}}</th>
                    <th>
                      
                      @if ( $movimiento > 90 && $ritmo > 90 )
                        <img src="{{ asset('img/cinco.png') }}" style="width:30%">
                      

                      @elseif ( $movimiento > 70 && $ritmo > 70 )
                        <img src="{{ asset('img/"cuatro.png') }}" style="width:30%">

                      @elseif ( $movimiento > 60 && $ritmo > 60 )
                        <img src="{{ asset('img/"tres.png') }}" style="width:30%">

                      @elseif ( $movimiento > 50 && $ritmo > 50 )
                        <img src="{{ asset('img/"dos.png') }}" style="width:30%">

                      @elseif ( $movimiento > 40 && $ritmo > 40 )
                        <img src="{{ asset('img/"una.png') }}" style="width:30%">

                      @else
                        <img src="{{ asset('img/"cero.png') }}" style="width:30%">
                      @endif

                    </th>
                    
                </tr>
                @endforeach
                
            </tbody>
```

And the problem is that it only shows the iage in the first if.
Here´s the example:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MugJW.png)
In the second row, as $movimiento is 75 and $ritmo is 100, and both are >70, it should display 'img/cuatro.png' but it doesn´t work.
I have tried using a switch instead of if/elseif but it happens still the same.
Any idea?

Comment: `asset('img/"tres.png')` - remove double quotes -> `asset('img/tres.png')` (all cases like this one) and it should work

Comment: Thank you ver much @InDevX. That´s the reason it didn´t work. Much as I looked at it, I couldn´t find the mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some inconsistencies with your quotes in the `src` attribute of the `img` tags.

It should be:

```php
<img src="{{ asset('img/cuatro.png') }}" style="width:30%">
```

And do the same for the other `img` tags:

```
@if ( $movimiento > 90 && $ritmo > 90 )
    <img src="{{ asset('img/cinco.png') }}" style="width:30%">

@elseif ( $movimiento > 70 && $ritmo > 70 )
    <img src="{{ asset('img/cuatro.png') }}" style="width:30%">

@elseif ( $movimiento > 60 && $ritmo > 60 )
    <img src="{{ asset('img/tres.png') }}" style="width:30%">

@elseif ( $movimiento > 50 && $ritmo > 50 )
    <img src="{{ asset('img/dos.png') }}" style="width:30%">

@elseif ( $movimiento > 40 && $ritmo > 40 )
    <img src="{{ asset('img/una.png') }}" style="width:30%">

@else
    <img src="{{ asset('img/cero.png') }}" style="width:30%">
@endif
```

Once you've corrected the quotes, it should properly display the corresponding images for each condition.

Comment: Thank you @exsnake. That was the mistake.